# Running coroutine for lerping color

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a coroutine where I am lerping to change a color from white to red. It works but it happens only once as the coroutine is run only once.

I want this to happen two or three times like a ping pong, without running the coroutine multiple times (as that would not be feasible).

It should lerp from white to red, then red to white and then again white to red in the end. Is there a way to do this in the coroutine shown below?

```
bool changingColor = false;

void Start(){
 StartCoroutine(LerpColor(this.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>(), Color.white, Color.red, 0.5f));
}

IEnumerator LerpColor (MeshRenderer mesh, Color fromColor, Color toColor, float duration) {
        if (changingColor) {
            yield break;
        }
        changingColor = true;
        float counter = 0;

        while (counter < duration) {
            counter += Time.deltaTime;

            float colorTime = counter / duration;
            Debug.Log (colorTime);

            //Change color
            mesh.material.color = Color.Lerp (fromColor, toColor, counter / duration);
            //Wait for a frame
            yield return null;
        }
        changingColor = false;
    }
```

Comment: Have you considered using a loop?

Comment: I am using a while loop in the code

Comment: Well, yeah. But then you're saying you want to do it multiple times. What does things multiple times? A loop!

Comment: ofc but as you see i dont want it to repeat in same pattern. I want it to lerp from white to red, red to white and then back to white to red.

Comment: So why not swap `fromColor` and `toColor` at the end of each iteration of the repeater loop?

Comment: will the for loop wait for the coroutine to complete before starting a new one?

Comment: Why wouldn't you put the loop in your Coroutine?

Comment: Hmm so I call the loop to run the coroutine inside the coroutine itself? I am sorry but I don't follow. Could you post the code as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't you just do something like this?:

```cs
IEnumerator LerpColor (MeshRenderer mesh, Color fromColor, Color toColor, float duration, int repetitions) {
    if (changingColor) {
        yield break;
    }
    changingColor = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < repetitions; ++i) {
        float counter = 0;

        while (counter < duration) {
            counter += Time.deltaTime;

            float colorTime = counter / duration;
            Debug.Log (colorTime);

            //Change color
            mesh.material.color = Color.Lerp (fromColor, toColor, counter / duration);
            //Wait for a frame
            yield return null;
        }
        Color tmp = fromColor;
        fromColor = toColor;
        toColor = tmp;
    }
    changingColor = false;
}
```

And call it like this?:

```
StartCoroutine(LerpColor(this.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>(), Color.white, Color.red, 0.5f, 4));
```

Or if you want to keep your method as it is, perhaps you could create a wrapper around it:

```cs
IEnumerator LerpColorRepeater(MeshRenderer mesh, Color fromColor, Color toColor, float repetitionDuration, int repetitions) {
    for (int i = 0; i < repetitions; ++i)
    {
        IEnumerator lerpColorEnumerator = LerpColor(mesh, i % 2 == 0 ? fromColor : toColor, i % 2 == 0 ? toColor : fromColor, repetitionDuration, repetitions);
        using (lerpColorEnumerator as IDisposable)
        {
            while (lerpColorEnumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                yield return lerpColorEnumerator.Current;
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

Usage:

```cs
StartCoroutine(LerpColorRepeater(this.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>(), Color.white, Color.red, 0.5f, 4));
```

Comment: Why would you manually iterate instead of using `foreach` (which additionally disposes the iterator correctly)

Comment: @Ben You can't `foreach` an `IEnumerator`. You're right about disposing it though.

Comment: This is actually a good solution with number of repetitions in the function :)

Comment: Ahh yeah, but the `yield return` syntax also works with a return type of `IEnumerable`, which should be preferred over `IEnumerator`.

Comment: @Ben Indeed, but Unity's `StartCoroutine` only supports `IEnumerator`, and while you can create one from an `IEnumerable`, I didn't want to break any existing uses of OP's original method / cause confusion.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing actually wrong with DiplomacyNotWar's approach, but there's a much simpler way:

- Warp the mixing factor through a periodic function

I also switched the loop to a for loop since you had all the classic for-loop steps.

```
IEnumerator PingPongColor (MeshRenderer mesh, Color fromColor, Color toColor, float duration, float durationEachPass) {
    if (changingColor) {
        yield break;
    }
    changingColor = true;
    for (float t = 0.0f; t < duration; t += Time.deltaTime) {
        float colorTime = t / durationEachPass;
        float mix = 0.5f * (1.0f - (float)Math.Cos(Math.PI * colorTime));
        Debug.Log($"colorTime={colorTime} mix={mix}");

        //Change color
        mesh.material.color = Color.Lerp(fromColor, toColor, mix);

        //Wait for a frame
        yield return null;
    }
    changingColor = false;
}
```

How it works:

1. The cosine function smoothly changes from 1.0 to -1.0 in Pi radians.  So `1 - cos(t * Pi)` smoothly changes from 0.0 to 2.0 in 1.0 input units.
2. An extra factor of 0.5 gives us a smooth change from 0.0 to 1.0 in 1.0 input units.
3. Cosine is symmetric and periodic, after reaching -1.0, it starts smoothly increasing back to 1.0.  So our `(1 - cos(t * Pi))/2` reverses at the same time, but it reached 1.0 and then returns smoothly to zero, then reverses again.

I would however recommend one additional change, to separate the calculation of the color sequence from the application to the mesh.

Comment: I do like this solution! It's more elegant than mine for sure.

Comment: thanks! I never thought Cos and PI will be used in a lerp function :) In Unity, instead of Math, we use Mathf. However the lerp does not work :( if I give duration < 2, there is no transition and also durationEachPass as 4 then, it does not repeat the transition.

Comment: @Vika: `durationEachPass` should be less than `duration`

Answer (score 0):

It can be done much simpler by using `Mathf.PingPong`

```
void Update() {
  mesh.material.color =
      Color.Lerp(Color.white, Color.red, Mathf.PingPong(Time.time, 1));
}
```

Comment: I really need to learn Unity! This is much simpler.

Comment: I know about Mathf.PingPong() function, I was avoiding using update() and wanted to do in coroutine. However, how do I control number of repetitions in the Update()? Because this just plays in a loop and I will never know when the color transition is completed and how many times.